# Finding the density of $X$

Tags: expected-value

Let $X$ be a random variable with $ E(X^m) = (m+1)! (2^m), \ m=1,2,3, ...$

Find the density of $X$.

I tried finding the nth derivative of the moment generating function to solve this question but somehow I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function   This Wikipedia article describes the expansion of the moment generation function in terms of the moments (which you have).

Comment: If you use the characteristic function instead of the moment generator, I suspect getting the distribution function (inverse Fourier transform of char. function) would be easier.

Comment: I don't understand could you solve it?

Comment: Char. function $\phi(t)$ can be used to get density function $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-itx}\phi(t)dt$.

Comment: $\phi(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{E(X^k)}{k!}(it)^k$.  It looks very similar to the series for the moment generation function.

Comment: Ok,I don't know about characteristic functions but I will try to understand .

Comment: Characteristic functions are very similar to moment generating functions.  They are Fourier transforms of probability density, rather than Laplace transforms (moment generator).  The main advantage is that the inverse transform to get the density is usually a lot easier.